# aggregations causing out of memory elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with some 10m records.
When I try to find distincts in one field (around 2m) my Java runs out of memory.
Can I implement a scan and scroll on this aggregation to retrieve the same data in smaller parts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check that how much RAM you have allocated for ElasticSearch, since it is optimized to be super fast it likes to consume lots of memory. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html

I'm not sure if this applies to cardinality aggregations (or are you using terms aggregation?), but I got some success with using "doc_values" fielddata format (see http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/disk-based-field-data-a-k-a-doc-values/), this takes more disk space but keeps less stuff in RAM. How many distinct values do you have? Returning back a JSON response on terms aggregation with a million distinct values is going to be fairly big. Cardinality aggregation just counts the number of distinct values without returning their individual values.

You could also try re-indexing your data with a larger number of shards, too big shards don't perform as well as a few smaller ones.

Comment: Oh, and this topic is better suited for http://serverfault.com, StackOverflow is about actual programming. :P